# angularjs2 cli, building chrome extension, troubles to defining content and background sripts

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, angular-cli

Say I've generated a new `angularjs-2` app with [cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli),
so that with `ng build` it *builds* my sources to `/dist` folder.

Since I'm building chrome extension, in `manifest.json`, I have to define where is my [content-script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) (that loads with page) and where is [background script/ event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) (that loads once).

So I have to define them in my `manifest.json`,

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*"],
      "css": ["content-script.css"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }

    "background": {
       "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
       "persistent": false
    },
```

The trouble is that when I configure `.angular-cli.json` to define what should be placed into `/dist` folder by `ng build` I'm a bit puzzled what to put where.

There is a script section, where I can put my content-script

```
  "scripts": [
    "content-script.ts"
  ],
```

then (whether it is one file or more) it will compile all in one dist/scripts.bundle.js

So then in my manifest.json I have to set:
 "content_scripts": [

```
{
  "matches": ["*"],
  "css": ["mystyles.css"],
  "js": ["scripts.bundle.js"]
}
```

But.. as I said there is only one `scripts.bundle.js`. What should I do for background /event page then ? (I can not load background one when I need content and vise versa).

That all sounds to me like as if in order to build a plugin with angularjs 2, I actually need build application with 3 angulaj apps in it:

- app for popup page (by click on ext icon)
- app for content page
- app for options page (by right click on ext icon)

(when I say `app`, I mean angularjs2 app)

CLI seems does [not support it](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4215)?
Are there any ways (others than not using CLI)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share my opinionated answer that fits my needs:

1. it is beneficial to keep using using angular cli, because it does all that stuff for you with building
2. then in cli project#1 one can create content scipt, in project#2 options page, etc. Then create a script that would build it for your in dist folder with these 3 projects. That should perfectly work.

Off-topic:

But.. at the same time, as said [here](https://twitter.com/starodubtsevss/status/725118418689642496). Taking unto account that my back-end is on `scala` and I one-man-on-the-project. Then I would rather go with `scalajs` and [scalajs + react + material components](http://chandu0101.github.io/sjrc/#materialui/tabs) seems that is growing faster than I thought (I'm surprised), and the build system as sbt would build me my chrome dist as I want so. Will give it a try. [It may be interesting for all "not-really-js-developers".]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without ejecting the Webpack config using Angular CLI. I figured it out after much swearing, hair pulling & keyboard smashing :)). The Chrome Extension documentation sucks so bad it's not funny. Adding in the Angular X docs is a force multiplier in the wrong direction ;)

The way it's working for me is like this:

Within your angular-cli.json file, there is an array in the "apps[0]" object called "assets": [image: Assets Array]

Anything that you put into the assets array is included in the dist folder when you run ng build. That's why in the image you can see I've included my manifest.json file, images, icons, etc. You can also just include a folder name, as long as any of the files / folders reside in the src directory of your angular app:

[image: Src Directory]

So you can see, I've also placed a folder called 'js' in my src directory, and referenced that in the angular-cli.json file simply as 'js' within the assets array.

My js folder is then included in the dist directory, and files within that folder (including background.js) can be referenced simply as 'js/filename.js':
[image: Referencing background.js]

I hope that helps anyone running into this issue. Extension development with new tech is almost not worth the effort, but if you can break through all the mess you'll be in rarefied air lol.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

@Ses,I was trying to also use angular-cli and build a Chrome extension that would have a background JS. After hitting a few dead ends ejecting it was the final solution. Even though angular-cli seems to be a consolidation of a lot of things, ejecting the webpack config and having to type 'npm run ' as opposed to ng  is a small step.

Run

```
Ng eject
```

Then in the new autogenerated webpack.config.js

```
  "entry": {
    ...
    "background": [
      "./src/background/background.ts"
    ],
    "content-scripts": [
      "./src/content-scripts.ts"
    ]
  },
...
// Added bonus, copy the manifest.json file as an asset
    new GlobCopyWebpackPlugin({
      "patterns": [
        "manifest.json",
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
```

You can always revert the ejection by changing the ejected property in .angular-cli.json. Enjoy.