# Building chrome extension popup, options and background using @angular/cli

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, angular-cli

I would like to create a chrome extension with popup, options page and a background process. So basically an angular app with popup.html, options.html and background.html pages. Is this possible with angular cli?

Today i can do this with multiple webpack configs for each page and it works. Now i want to replace it with angular-cli. Can anyone point me to right direction, i.e a seed project or starter example

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430369/angularjs2-cli-building-chrome-extension-troubles-to-defining-content-and-back i will see if this works out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a LOT of struggling, and digging through the hints and tips on [surya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209609/surya)'s answer, I've managed to get my solution working using Angular (9).

---

### manifest.json

```
{
...
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "/index.html#/popup"
    },
    "options_page": "/index.html#/options",
    "background": {
        "page": "/index.html#/background",
        "persistent": false
    },
...
}
```

It uses the [hash location strategy](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy) to load the components via the `#`.

---

### AppRouting

The routing will use the paths specified, and load the appropriate components (`popup`, `options`, and `background script` respectively)

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'popup', component: PopupComponent },
    { path: 'options', component: OptionsComponent },
    { path: 'background', component: BackgroundComponent },
    { path: '**', component: PopupComponent },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

where the `AppRoutingModule` is referenced in the `app.module.ts`:

> **Note:** I've created feature modules for my `Options` and `Popup` components, but for this answer it's unrelated. You can declare the mentioned components here as well as I've done with the `BackgroundComponent`.

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        BackgroundComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        OptionsModule,
        PopupModule
    ],
    providers: [
         // This is needed because the manifest loads the index.html file, followed by a #, 
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

With the routing set up, we can use that in the app.component (the bootstrapped component) to load the correct component via the route:

### index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Your Extension title</title>
    <base href="/index.html#/"> <!-- !!Important!! !-->

    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root> <!-- Root of your application !-->
</body>

</html>
```

### AppComponent

The app component (for simplicity) only contains the `<router-outlet>`, and will orchestrate which component to load.

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

> **Note:** The `base href` in the `index.html` file must be set to the following: `/index.html#/`, otherwise consecutive reloads on the options/popup page will not recognise the correct route and throw a `File not found` response page.

---

#### Examples

If you navigate to a URL, you can see the routing working on the different components:

Options

`chrome-extension://<Extension ID>/index.html#/options`

Popup

`chrome-extension://<Extension ID>/index.html#/popup`

Background

> Even though this component acts just as a background script, you can still use it as a normal Angular component - and still make use of Angular's features - like services, injection, etc.

`chrome-extension://<Extension ID>/index.html#/background`

Comment: After trying both approaches, I found this to be the better solution. Because the query approach uses a redirect, which can cause some confusion for users and extra work for developers. Going to `index.html?page=options` would redirect to `index.html` but with the options page loaded, on refresh it would load either the popup or 404 page (depending on how the routing is defined.)

To me this hash solution sparks something in my developer brain that says it looks ugly (the hash being before the slash) but it works well.

Answer (score 5):

So after lot of googling, this [blog post](https://cito.github.io/blog/web-ext-with-angular/) helped me.
TLDR; no need of multiple apps, single app will do using query parameters. for example in my manifest.json i now have this

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html?page=popup"
},
"options_page": "index.html?page=options",
"background": {
    "page": "index.html?page=background",
    "persistent": false
},
```

And then after defining different components (PopupComponent, OptionsComponent and BackgroundComponent) in Routes, navigate based on the 'page' param.

Comment: Can you specify what your routing looks like? I've tried the above but to no avail.

Comment: You can also try https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#multiple-projects this creates separate html file for each application

Comment: I've actually managed to get it working - by adding route listeners in the app.component, grabbing the `queryParameter` and calling `router.navigate([...])`, which loads the correct component. Now I'm just having issues with the `content_script` not being loaded - this is a separate bundled file using a custom webpack configuration (as `page.js`), but for some reason I can't seem to get the file loaded via the `content_scripts` section.

Comment: You can try to create a separate empty project and only make the content_script load using ur custom webpack config. this way it will eliminate all other variables.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to load another project if you're going to end up using custom webpack config anyways - I'll upload my solution here when I get a chance.